# content in vue 3 component does not update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'am struggling to understand why my component does not reflects the current state of the content I put in.

see below the component, you can also access it [here](https://github.com/bimdata/platform-next/blob/develop/src/components/specific/app/app-side-panel/AppSidePanel.vue)

AppSidePanel

```js
<template>
  <teleport :to="`#app-side-panel-container--${side}`">
    <transition :name="`slide-fade-${side}`">
      <div
        v-show="showSidePanel"
        class="app-side-panel"
        :style="`--header-height: ${header ? '44px' : '0px'}`"
      >
        <div v-if="header" class="app-side-panel__header">
          <slot name="header">
            <span class="app-side-panel__header__title">
              {{ title }}
            </span>
            <BIMDataButton ghost rounded icon @click="closeSidePanel">
              <BIMDataIcon name="close" size="xxs" fill color="granite-light" />
            </BIMDataButton>
          </slot>
        </div>
        <div class="app-side-panel__content">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </teleport>
</template>
```

Here is how I use the component

```js
<AppSidePanel>
   <BuildingMaker
     :apiClient="apiClient"
     :space="project.cloud"
     :project="project"
     :model="currentModel"
     @metaBuilding-created="loadProjectModels(project)"
     @metaBuilding-deleted="loadProjectModels(project)"
   />
</AppSidePanel>
```

Here is what I expect:

- when I click open ('Créer') the BuildingMaker component -> I want to display the home of the component -> working
- when I click edit ('Editer') a specific building -> I want to display the specific building within the BuildingMaker component -> not working

instead of that, the home of MetaBuilding component is displayed!

[image]

BuildingMaker component - Home
[image]

BuildingMaker component - Specific building[image]

What I checked:

- with hardcoding in order to replace AppSidePanel, the expected view is displayed according if I want to see the home or a specific building within the BuildingMaker component

```js
<transition name="slide-fade-right">
  <div v-if="isBMOpen" class="pdf-manager__building-maker">
    <div class="pdf-manager__building-maker__header">
      <BIMDataButton ghost rounded icon @click="closeBM">
        <BIMDataIcon name="close" size="xxs" fill color="granite-light" />
      </BIMDataButton>
    </div>
    <div class="pdf-manager__building-maker__content">
      <BuildingMaker
        :apiClient="apiClient"
        :space="project.cloud"
        :project="project"
        :model="currentModel"
        @metaBuilding-created="loadProjectModels(project)"
        @metaBuilding-deleted="loadProjectModels(project)"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</transition>
```

According to me the problem could comes from the use of teleport + transition + slot, I would say that Vue can't handle nicely with these 3 at the same time.

Any suggestion ?